# Start a service before or at windows7 login screen?

Tags: session

As the same way ,As a password authentication is done on start up , i need my program to run there along with it, like lenovo's face recognition(veriface). Thanx for any help guys :)

Comment: I am literally in need of a solution .....geeks , waiting for u r responses

Answer (score -1):

D you want to use face recognition as login authentication. If its yes you better opt for [blink software](http://www.luxand.com/blink/)

Comment: no sir, i want some other program which i coded by me ,say any EXE file like that (C program out put)